# Перевод английского термина "linearithmic" O(N * log N) на русский

Tags: алгоритм, терминология, сложность, перевод

`Linearithmic time complexity` - линейно-логарифмическая сложность, `O(N * log N)`

Есть ли какие-то "короткие" переводы слова **`linearithmic`**?

Примеры  (выдуманые мной и из комментов) [длинна слова]:

- `логлинейное`             [11]
- `линеарное`               [9]
- `линлогное`               [9]
- `линарифмическое`         [15]
- `линейнологарифмическое`  [22]

Еще варианты?

Comment: Не понимаю, что значит короткие переводы?

Comment: одним словом, как linearithmic, например, "линеарное", или "логлинейное", или "линлогное"

Comment: хм, сомневаюсь что в русском языке есть такое понятие, за все свои курсы в университете ни разу не встречал.

Comment: Ближе всего *линарифмический*, ну, а какой именно звучит получше - кто ж тут судья? В Интернете пока нет не то что устоявшегося - никакого термина.

Comment: Вроде сказать "n log n" (эн лог эн) тоже как-то недолго.

Comment: @Qwertiy "эн" короче чем "линейный", но говорим-то "линейный"...

Comment: @Harry, ну далеко не всегда говорим :)

Comment: Линейнологарифмическое

Answer (score 2):

Исходя из того, что термин: *Linearithmic* не является общепринятым, то есть ну не Оксфорд, а больше компьютерный сленг, я бы предложил термин *логлинейный*:

1. Он конечно не описан в словарях Даля и Ожегова (то есть примерно идентичен *linearithmic*)
2. Относительно благозвучен, легко склоняется (в противовес *линлогное*)
3. Передает смысл (в противовес *линеарное*)

Comment: Тогда уж *логнейный*.

Answer (score 1):

Ставлю на линарифмический.

Потому что "логнейный" звучит гораздо хуже :)

А давайте устроим пари - какой термин первым появится в русскоязычной литературе? :)

> — «Хливкие» — это хлипкие и ловкие. «Хлипкие» значит то же, что и «хилые». Понимаешь, это слово как бумажник. Раскроешь, а там два отделения! Так и тут — это слово раскладывается на два!
>   (c) Льюис Кэрролл, *Алиса в Зазеркалье*

**Update**

В [этой книжке](http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-907144-08-8.html) встречается *линарифмическая* сложность :)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а есть какая-то общая платформа для голосования? Сделать там голосовалку с вариантами и нагнать IT-хомячков, чтобы проголосовали.

Comment: Какой сейчас выберут - тот и появится)

Comment: @eri Ну значит, пари о том, какой сейчас выберут :)

Comment: @eri См. дополненный ответ.

Comment: `Ставлю на логлинейный. Потому что "линический" звучит гораздо хуже :)` А вообще, конечно же линеарифмический.

Answer (score 0):

Википедия говорит, что линейно-логарифмическая функция является частным случаем квазилинейной, так что этот термин тоже можно использовать как перевод.